# Integral of products in the Laplace domain

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

Suppose I have two functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$ (in fact they are nonnegative measures), and I would like to find the integral of their product, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x)dx$.

However, I only know the two-sided Laplace transforms of the two functions. That is, I have equations for
$$
F(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{sx}f(x)dx,\qquad\text{and}\qquad G(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}g(x)dx.
$$
Is there a 'nice' formula for the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x)dx$ in terms of the functions $F$ and $G$, without first having to perform their inverse Laplace transforms?

Comment: Perhaps you could apply the Plancherel theorem (similar to Parseval's theorem)?

Comment: i think it's true that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(s)G(s)ds = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x)dx$.

Comment: You may be interested by the answer here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44713/when-i-can-safely-assume-that-a-function-is-a-laplace-transform-of-other-functio

Comment: @mathworker21 if that's true it's not at all obvious. If you can find a reference or sketch a proof, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @LL3.14 can you say specifically which part of which answer you think might be helpful? I know the inverse Laplace transforms of $F$ and $G$ exist, because they are defined as the Laplace transforms of $f$ and $g$. What I'm trying to do is give a formula for the given integral without first needing to find the functions $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @Nathaniel ok, i might have been [off a bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis).

Comment: As in the accepted answer in my link, you could extend your functions to the complex plane, and then use the Plancherel theorem for the Fourier transform (which gives the Parseval identity at the end of the accepted answer, but you would have to replace it by the product of two different functions)

Comment: @mathworker21 thank you - that doesn't quite solve my problem, but it's useful and I didn't know it.

Comment: @LL3.14 thank you, that's helpful too. I'm really trying to avoid going into the complex plane, as that will make the rest of what I'm doing a lot more complicated - I should have said that explicitly - but it's good to know I can do that if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Laplace-transform is just the Fourier-transform rotated by 90 degrees, one can do the usual tricks: (Up to some constants) The integral is the Fourier-Laplace-transform evaluated at zero and the F/L-transform of a product is the convolution of the individual transforms. So we expect a formula of the form $\int f(x)g(x) = const\cdot (F\ast G)(0)$.

More precisely: If $\widehat{\cdot}$ denotes the unitary Fourier transform $\widehat{f}(\xi) = (2\pi)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)e^{-ix\xi} dx$ (if $f\in L^1$), then the constant works out to be 1:
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f(x) g(x) dx = \sqrt{2\pi}\widehat{f\cdot g}(0) = (\widehat{f} \ast \widehat{g})(0) = (F(is)\ast G(is))(0) = \int_\mathbb{R} F(is)G(-is)ds$$
(assuming of course that $f,g,F$ and $G$ are sufficiently nice)

Comment: Hi @Johannes Hanh, nice derivation. Could you elaborate on what you meant by "rotated by 90°"?  Is going from $s=i\omega$ to $s=x+i\omega$ what you mean by such a rotation?

Comment: I mean that the only difference between the two is the factor $i$ in the exponential: $\mathcal{F}f(\xi) = \int f(x) e^{i x \xi} dx$ while $\mathcal{L}f(s) = \int f(x) e^{-sx} dx$. And multiplying by $i$ or $-i$ is just a 90 degree rotation of the complex plane

Comment: I think there is a mistaking the inverse transforms with the "forward" transforms, no? Looking at the definition you gave the "forward" Fourier transform (FT) should read: $\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)e^{-i\xi x} dx$ and the definition of the Laplace transform (LT) is $F{f}(\gamma + i \xi) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)e^{-\gamma x -i\xi x} dx$. I see that the OP gave a definition with a change of sign for the LT that indeed would induce the 90° rotation. However, it is not the usual definition for the LT, which is usually defined for $\gamma >0$ (ROC). Clearer to me know thx!

Comment: The sign doesn't really matter. That's just the question if you rotated 90° left or right. The $\gamma>0$ isn't really problematic as well. For one, the domain of definition has to be rotated as well, of course. And second, in many cases one can extend to $\gamma=0$ by taking a limit in an appropriate space of distributions. (Distributions are the right framework to think about both transformations anyway)